# Hide executables in the VSCode explorer/sidebar - Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, executable

When I compile my C++ programs, the executables tend to show up in my VSCode explorer/sidebar which is annoying when your workspace has a ton of them. I want to have a setting through which they no longer appear there like the `.git` folder.

When I was on windows, I could put `**/.exe` in the *Files to exclude* list but on linux(pop!_OS), the executables seem to have no extension and so, I don't know what to put in that list. I tried putting in `**/.` (which I didn't think would work), and it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

In settings Files > Files: Exclude
or settings.json

```
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/Thumbs.db": true,
    "**/.exe": true
  },
```

Comment: The title clearly specifies that the question is for Linux. Your solution only works for windows which I mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: I have Linux, I just provided the path to the settings and the config file from my system

Comment: But it doesn't work and isn't supposed to work since linux doesn't use .exe files